# Does anyone recognise this Taylor series expansion of an exp-like function?

Tags: real-analysis

Does anyone recognise this Taylor series expansion? It is similar to that of $\exp(x)$, but not quite:

$$
1 - \frac{1}{2!}x + \frac{1}{3!}x^2 - \frac{1}{4!}x^3 + \frac{1}{5!}x^4 - \frac{1}{6!}x^5 + \ldots
$$

Is this a well-known function? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: How about $$x-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}-\cdots?$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Lord Shark the Unknown, looks like user284331 used this as a step in his derivation.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
S(x)&=1-\dfrac{1}{2!}x+\dfrac{1}{3!}x^{2}-\cdots\\
&=\dfrac{1}{x}\left(x-\dfrac{1}{2!}x^{2}+\dfrac{1}{3!}x^{3}-\cdots\right)\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{x}\left(-x+\dfrac{1}{2!}x^{2}-\dfrac{1}{3!}x^{3}+\cdots\right)\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{x}(e^{-x}-1).
\end{align*}

And define $S(0)=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much, user284331.